# Как управлять вьюшками через класс ViewModel

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Не понимаю как управлять вью, например CheckBoxом через MVVM во ViewModel классе, насколько я понял нужно обертать их в лайвдату и в классе фрагмента слушать через observe. Хотелось бы получить пример кода как это делается

Comment: миллионы примеров, гайдов, туторов, нужно только загуглить... https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata, https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Чтобы подписаться на liveData в viewmodel cоздайте MutableLiveData и LiveData в viewModel**

1. MutableLiveData чтобы постит данные, так как вы не можете постит
   данные через liveData
2. LiveData чтобы подписаться в фрагменте/активити

Код в viewModel

```
private val _checkBoxEvent = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
val checkBoxEvent: LiveData<Boolean> = _checkBoxEvent
```

В фрагменте/активити подпишитесь на liveData

```
viewModel.checkBoxEvent.observe(this) { value ->
    // do something with value
}
```

Чтобы постит данные используйте mutableLiveData в viewModel

```
_checkBoxEvent.value = true
```

**А чтобы передать какие-то данные из активити/фрагмент в viewmodel объявите функцию в viewmodel**

```
fun onCheckBoxClicked(isChecked: Boolean) {
   //do something with value     
}
```

И в активити/фрагмент отправьте данные на viewmodel

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
    viewModel.onCheckBoxClicked(isChecked)
}
```